# Why do shorted PSU probes stick together just a bit, even on very low power?

Tags: power-supply, physics

I'm using a standard bench power supply set to 3.6V and 0.5A. I also tried 0.05A.

I then bring the positive and negative terminals together in a short circuit, and I noticed there is a noticable sticking effect between them. I have to use slightly more force to separate them, than when the power supply is turned off.

Is this some kind of electromechanical phenomenon, or is there some degree of welding going on here?

Comment: +1 for experimenting a bit. Ppl tend to ask first and try later (if at all) nowadays. But please, never try high currents ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, this is welding. Every PSU has a a sizable output capacitor (100 - 1000 uF), and when the leads are shorted, the cap gets discharged first, with much higher impulse of current than the PSU is set to, before the steady DC current regulation comes into effect.